# System.Web.helpers.json encode UTC datetime issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC5 & jquery, i'm trying to handle a known issue of datetime conversion problem with the json ecoding.
on my view, i'm using the following line to create a json object on the view:

```
@Html.Hidden("boxJson", Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(item)));
```

everything works prefect, since this 'item' im encoding is a complex object containing some inner classes, but the encoding works prefect, EXCEPT the datetime. i already managed to handle the enclosed string (ex: /Date(1078729200000)/) for a date on the client side with some client functions. but couldn't handle the UTC issue that this Encode function does to dates.

[for those who are no familiar with it, the Encode function handles Datetime coming from DB, where the datetime has the property *kind* is set to Unspecified, as UTC time automatically.]

I know i might do some work around and manipulate the dates in the json by some client function, but im using the whole json object POSTing it back to the server without interfering.

```
var jsonObject =  $('#boxJson').val();
$.ajax({
                url: 'some url\Func',
                type: 'POST',
                data: jsonObject ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Func(Class jsonObject ){
//jsonObject comes with all class and inner class members BUT dates are in UTC timezone
...
}
```

which, again works fine, except of the UTC datetime.

I've tried to use:

```
 @Html.Hidden("boxJson" , Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)));
```

which fixed the date problem, but couldn't handle my complex 'item' object.

basically, i'm looking for a way to override the Json.Encode method with some method that handles the UTC datetime issue. 
or any other workaround will be helpful as well.

**UPDATE**

my complex class 'item':

```
public class ScheduleResult : IComparable<ScheduleResult>
    {
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }   
        public ServiceRequest Request { get; set; }
        public ProviderResource AssignedResource { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Finish { get; set; }
        public ScheduleEvaluation ScheduleEvaluation { get; set; }
        public int Ranking { get; set; } 
    }
```

ServiceRequest , ProviderResource , ScheduleEvaluation are also classes.

Comment: JSON.NET is a great library and would indeed be my recommendation for fixing the DateTime formatting problem. I'm not sure I understand what is the problem withe the complex 'item' object, could you please include the code for the relevant class(es)?

Comment: Thanks for adding, so what is precisely the problem with serializing a `ScheduleResult`? Do you get an error?

Comment: not at all, when i serialize from the view to the client, the datetime is changed to UTC time. so the client 'holds' the wrong time, and when im posting to the server i'm not changing the time so i stay with a wrong time zone. (talking about the Json.Encode)

Comment: I gather the date issue gets resolved when you use json.net instead of Json.Encode. But its not clear what your other problem is that involves the complex `ScheduleResult` object

Comment: @elolos, thank's for your help. my two other objects are flat object, they are classes we created that aren't inheriting from other type (List, IComparable ect.) so the Json.NET doesn't serialize them... eventually, i will do some different work around at this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more coding, i figured that my problem using Json.NET was derived classes i have, in my example: ServiceRequest, ProviderResource are of this kind.
so the Json.NET needs the attributes [DataContract] for the class, and [DataMemeber] for each class property to be able to serialize the class.